# nginx $request_filename 301 redirect with parsing

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, pcre

Very simple rewrite, but it suddenly doesn`t work.

Need one link 301 to other, but "some-text-here" must be parsed and used in var before

www.host.com/some-text-here/url1/
to
www.host.com/some-text-here/url2/

---

```
if ( $request_filename ~ ([^.*]+)/url1/ ) {
   rewrite ^ $1/url2/? permanent;
}
```

---

Comment: You don't need `if` here. BTW, your regexp is absurd unless you really want to exclude *period* and *asterisk* symbols

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is regexp I used before. Maybe it don`t fit here. You know how to get all url string before /url1/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `if`. This line should be enough:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)/url1/ /$1/url2/? permanent;
```